# Looping through a session in an array and save to database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I save cart items in session which is in array, when i want to loop through it and save all the items customers selected to database, only the first item will be saved.

Here is my code, am using Codeigniter 4

```
 public function cartpayment()
 {
     foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $row) {   
         $data = [
             'ord_prod'=> $row['ord_prod'],
             'ord_price'=> $row['ord_price'],
             'ord_ref' => uniqid(),
             'ord_qty' => (int)$row['ord_qty'],
             'ord_cus' => $row['ord_cus'],
         ];

         if($this->PaymentModel->cartPayment($data))
         {
            return redirect()->to('/');
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you're redirecting the user if the first `cartPayment()` call was successful. When you have a `return` (no matter if it's a redirect or not), nothing else after that in the function will be executed.

Comment: Looks like the IF condition is true so the code runs only once and redirects. Comment IF out and see the database for results.

Comment: Thank you all, I remove the IF and is working fine.